# How to simplify the abstract vector operation in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

for example, I have two vectors:

```
   a,b
```

I need to simplify the following simple equation :

```
|a+b|==|a-b|
```

We can know by artificial calculation:

```
 a.b==0
```

Now I tried the following expression  in Mathematica:

```
In[1040]=
         Reduce[{a, b} \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals] && (a + b).(a + b) == (a - b).(a - b)]
```

but keep it as it is.

```
Out[1040]=
        Reduce[(a | b) \[Element] Reals && (a + b).(a + b) == (a - b).(a - b)]
```

Comment: Just so you know, there's a dedicated [mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) sister site.

Comment: Mathematica is very often very bad at dealing with abstract vectors, where you just tell it the name of two unknown vectors and do not provide at least a list of symbols for the contents of the vector. That probably explains why you are having difficulties getting the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

With a little help with `TensorReduce`:

```
assumptions = Element[#, Vectors[2, Reals]] & /@ {a, b};
Reduce@TensorReduce[(a + b).(a + b) == (a - b).(a - b), Assumptions->assumptions]
```

Output:

```
a.b == 0
```

Comment: Can you explain this? why just  reduce can not work and  Reduce must  be combined with TensorReduce? I do not understand the reason.

Comment: @tiankonghewo It's probably due to the internal implementation. `TensorReduce` is equipped with tensor transformation rules from linear algebra while `Reduce` is equipped with transformation rules for scalars. Most importantly, *it's not perfect*. The best practice is always experiment with it.